# How to use react hook form's Controller with radio buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

**The Problem:**

- Controller isn't working as I'd expect and I'm unable to register radio buttons in react hook form. It shows up as undefined.

**What I'm trying to do:**

- I have a reusable `WrapperRadio` component that sets up `Controller` and then renders my atomic `RadioButton` component. I then use `WrapperRadio` within `RegistrationForm` and want to be able to see the selected radio button value in the console when I hit the GetValues or Submit button.
- The end goal is ultimately to be able to specify the number/content of the atomic RadioButton component as children of WrapperRadio. This would allow me to re-use it but I'm try to get Controller working with a single input field before I move on.

Examples:

- [Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-rain-5fvoz3?file=/src/atoms/RadioButton.tsx:831-1153)

Code Sandbox

1. Use WrapperRadio in RegistrationForm

```
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <WrapperRadio
        control={control}
        name="radioSelection"
        label="This is a label"
      />
    ...
    </form>
```

2. Using Controller in WrapperRadio

```
    return (
        <div>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name={name}
            render={({ field }) => <RadioButton {...field} label={label} />}
          />
        </div>
      );
```

3. Atomic RadioButton component

```
    return (
        <fieldset className="max-w-sm">
          <input
            ref={ref}
            id={name}
            name={name}
            type="radio"
            aria-label={label}
            {...props}
          />
          <label htmlFor={name} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
            {label}
          </label>
        </fieldset>
      );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use WrapperRadio in RegistrationForm - you should pass in a default value.

   ```
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
         <WrapperRadio
           control={control}
           name="radioSelection"
           label="This is a label"
           value={true}
         />
       </form>
   ```
2. Using Controller in WrapperRadio

   ```
           return (
             <div>
                <Controller
                 control={control}
                 name={name}
                 render={({ field: {onChange, ...props} }) => 
                 <RadioButton
                 onChange={e => onChange(e.target.checked)}
                 {...props} label={label} />}
              />
             </div>
   ```

Comment: Why is the value prop I use in WrapperRadio in RegistrationForm getting converted to true even if I pass a string like value="blue"? Once I start adding in multiple radio inputs I need each one to have a unique value.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that allows the input's value to be read as a string but has the downside of putting the onChange in the atomic RadioButton component (instead of keeping it stateless).

1. WrapperRadio in RegistrationForm

`options` is an array of the desired radio button answer options which makes the `WrapperRadio` reusable.

```
    <WrapperRadioGroup
      name="radioSelection"
      label="This is a radio group label"
      control={control}
      options={ ["chocolate", "vanilla" ] }
      value="ice-cream"
     >
```

2. Controller in WrapperRadio

Map through `options` to create a new radio button label for each one and pass `onChange` to the atomic RadioButton component.

```
return (
    <>
      {/* {label} */}
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        defaultValue={props.value}
        render={({ field: {onChange, ...props} }) => 
          options.map((option, index) => (
    
           <RadioButton
             key={index}
             {...props} 
             onChange={onChange}
             value={option}  
             label={label} 
          />
          ))
        }
      />
    </>  

  )
```

3. Atomic RadioButton component

`onChange` updates rhf's form state with the correct value

```
return (
      <>
        <input 
          ref={ref} 
          name={name} 
          type="radio" 
          value={value} 
          aria-label={label}
          onChange={ () => props.onChange(props.value) }
          {...props} />
        <label htmlFor={name}>Radio answer option</label>
      </>
    )
  }
```